What does a FDR of 0.05 really mean
I recently study about the FDR. A FDR of 0.05 indicates that around 5% of significantly reported results are actually false positives. Is this always the case? I tried this on a dataset and I found that even if I set a FDR of 0.05, I still get around 20% of false positives when tested against the ground truth.

What do you mean by "set a false discovery rate"?  How did you "set" it?

@PeterFlom, I mean filter the candidates based on the adjusted p value of < 0.05 using Benjamini Hochberg procedure. From my understanding, it should only give around 5% of false positives. However, I still find 20% of false positives.

Please provide additional details. How did you set the ground truth ? Did you simulate data under the null ?

@MangnierLoïc, we have the ground truth because we simulated the gene expression data. So, we will know exactly whether a gene is differentially expressed across conditions. By fitting the data on a model I crafted, I performed hypothesis testing to test whether the distribution is more likely to be null or alternative. Together with Benjamini Hochberg procedure to obtain the adjusted p value. Using this adjusted p value of 0.05, I try to control for FDR to be 0.05 (if my understanding is correct) . However, I realised that there are around 20% of the genes wrongly reported as significant.

Does your collection of p-values satisfy the B-H conditions for validity?  B-H isn't universally valid.

The first thing I would recommend  is to check how is your Type-I error rate before correction. I expect a severe inflation. Now the remaining question is why you observe that? Is the model you are using correct ? I can provide an answer with general concepts for this kind of question.


A FDR of 0.05 indicates that around 5% of significantly reported results are actually false positives.

Not quite—a FDR of .05 indicates that in expectation, 5% of significantly reported results are false positives. Whether the actual proportion of false discoveries is "around 5%" or not is subject to random chance.

Is this always the case?

Well, controlling for the FDR properly means that the expected proportion of false discoveries is whatever you set the FDR to be (e.g. .05). But many procedures to control for FDR (e.g. Benjamini-Hochberg) require a specific set of assumptions, which may not be met in your example (credit to @jbowman for mentioning this in the comments). If the assumptions are not met, then your FDR may be different than what you set it to be.
Also, even if you have done everything "correctly," it is still possible (albeit unlikely) to have around 20% of your discoveries be false positives. For example, if after controlling for a FDR of .05, you had 5 discoveries from 5 independent tests, there is still a ~23% chance that at least one of those discoveries is a false positive.
